# Custom Font not always displays correct in webView

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uiwebview

I am using a costum font in my eBookReader-App for a book requires it to display formulars.
The font  is added to the app and most of the times it is displayed correct.
But sometimes it isn't and the formulars are display large and fat.
 
I have no idea why this happens. The fonts are in copied into the bundle and are available:

[image]

The css in the book looks like this:

[image]

The css is linked in each xhtml-file the webView is loading:
[image]

Why is it working most of the times but sometimes not?

Answer (score 0):

You need set the url on the webview (then your app can find images and fonts from the project):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:myHtmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: I updated my question so that it is clearer. The webView is loading eBook-xhmtl-files and in each header the css with the fonts is linked. Do you mean I need another htmlFile to point to? What should be in it?